# AngularJs: How to Format Data in an Input?

Tags: input, formatting, angularjs

**Problem**

I need to format an input field visually in order to help the user know what they should type as a phone number.  For example, I want to accept a phone number as being a 3 digit area code, 3 digit prefix and 4 digit suffix:  (207) 555-1212.  I want to:

1. provide the helper formatting to the input field -- those parentheses and the hyphen
2. I don't want the 'helper' characters to be included in the actual data I store in my model.
3. As the user types, I want the parentheses to magically appear, then have the hyphen also appear at the right point.

What's the best way to do it?

*Note*:  This is not for displaying of a number -- I could use a filter for that.  This is for formatting data within an `input` field.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: perhaps you need a custom input field (a widget)?

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking for a simple solution, you could give AngularUI a try, http://angular-ui.github.com/

This is the example from the "Mask" section of that page:

```
<input ng-model="maskDemo" ui-mask="'99-99-9999'">
```

The "9"'s are numbers, and other stuff is just a mask / placeholders. It should only submit the actual values. You would edit the mask to include parentheses and anything else you may need.

Comment: The only downside to this is that when the phone number is viewed elsewhere, or saved in a database, it will look like "9999999999".

Comment: @MyCodeSucks that's usually what you will want, strip any non-digits, then any time you want to display your formatted number, you just apply the `ui-mask` to it.